# Applying stl algorithms to multidimensional vectors (vector<vector<T> >)

Tags: c++, vector, stl

How, generally, can an `stl` algorithm be applied to a multidimensional vector (i.e. a `vector<vector<T> >`)?

---

For example, if I wanted to fill some vector, `myVector`, with values according to some function, `myFunc()`, I might use something like:

`std::generate(myVector.begin() myVector.end(), myFunc())`

Suppose now that `myVec` is a `vector<vector<T> >`. How might I use `std::generate` to populate every element of every vector in `myVec` according to `myFunc`? Need I use a loop (barring all other considerations)?

Would I simply write something like:

`std::generate(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::generate(...))`

Surprisingly, I cannot find anything on this here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator passed to `std::generate()` needs to return a type that is assignable to the element type of the container.  So, in your example, the element type of `myVector` is another `vector`, so `myFunc()` would need to return a whole `vector`, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
vector<T> myFunc()
{
    vector<T> v;
    // populate v as needed...
    return v;
}

vector<vector<T> > myVector(some size);
std::generate(myVector.begin() myVector.end(), myFunc<T>);
```

Otherwise, you will have to do something more like this instead:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void myFunc(vector<T> &v)
{
    // populate v as needed...
}

vector<vector<T>> myVector(some size);
for(auto &v : myVector) {
    myFunc(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With range library (as [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)), you might flatten your vectors to work with vector of less dimension:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(4, std::vector<int>(3));

auto flattened = v | ranges::view::join;

std::generate(begin(flattened), end(flattened), [n = 0]() mutable{ return n++; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2c074d5ebb06957)

Else, regular loop seems the simpler:

```
auto gen = [n = 0]() mutable{ return n++; }
for (auto& inner : v) {
    std::generate(begin(inner), end(inner), gen);
}
```

You cannot really nest `generate` calls as it doesn't take current element to know size of each inner vector.